# csv file not downloading in chrome browser from asp.net c# app

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

i m using the following code to send a csv file through http request.The code runs fine but the file is not downloaded on client machine , not save as menu ,nothing appears . The same code i have used for another report and it works fine and file is also downloaded . I m running the project on local host.  but not for the button btnGenerateReport.

```
protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MHSProgressNotesBL oMHSProgressNote = new MHSProgressNotesBL();
        int ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClients.SelectedValue);
        int LocationId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlLocations.SelectedValue);
        int PractitionerId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPractitioner.SelectedValue);

        dt = oMHSProgressNote.FetchBillingReport(LocationId, ClientId, PractitionerId, Convert.ToDateTime(txtNoteStartDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(txtNoteEndDate.Text));
        WriteToCSV(dt);

    }

    private void WriteToCSV(DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {
            string attachment = "attachment; filename=ClientRoster.csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            WriteColumnName(dt);
            foreach (DataRow clientdata in dt.Rows)
            {
                WriteUserInfo(clientdata);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }

    }

    private void WriteColumnName(DataTable dt)
    {
        string columnNames = "";
        // Write Header row
        foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (item.ColumnName.Contains(','))
            {
                columnNames += "\"" + item.ColumnName + "\"";
            }
            else
            {
                columnNames += item.ColumnName + ",";
            }
        }
        columnNames = columnNames.TrimEnd(',');

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void WriteUserInfo(DataRow clientDataRow)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in clientDataRow.ItemArray)
        {
            AddComma((string)(item == System.DBNull.Value ? "" : item.ToString()), stringBuilder);
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

    }

    private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        if (value.Contains('"'))
        {
            value = value.Replace(@"""", @"""""");
            value = "\"" + value + "\"";
        }
        else if (value.Contains(','))
        {
            value = "\"" + value + "\"";
        }
        stringBuilder.Append(value);
        stringBuilder.Append(",");
    }
```

Comment: you really need to refactor the code. its poor maintainability and can cause problems - you should have a function which generates the CSV output or file and then have the caller write to the Response so everything is in easy manageable chunks rather than different methods all writing to the Response stream. This will also make it easier to target the problems you have and will encounter.

Answer (score 1):

The code is ok ......... the main problem was the button btnGenerateReport was inside of a update panel .Due to which an error was rising :The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'Client,Practitioner,'.
 The code worked fine after placing the button outside of update panel.

Comment: yes, exactly. you cannot write to an area where you have the update panel.